# In Java can you limit the input to where only a number can be entered or only a certain amount of numbers can be entered?

Tags: java

In Java can you limit the input using the scanner to where only a certain types such as numbers or letters can be entered. Also can you limit input to a certain amount of characters that can be entered?

Comment: in the standard Java console? No, you can't.

Comment: with another thread running key-simulator, you could instantly delete what you type. I tried that on an online word-typing-race game, it should work on scanner too.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot do that.
However, you could check if the user's input is an integer and also less than a certain amount of characters and if not prompt them to try again:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int getIntInputBelowCertainLength(String prompt, Scanner scanner, int maxLength) {
        int validInteger = -1;
        System.out.print(prompt);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                validInteger = scanner.nextInt();
                if (String.valueOf(validInteger).length() <= maxLength) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Input integer was too long, try again...");
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid input, must be an integer, try again...");
                System.out.print(prompt);
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        return validInteger;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int maxLength = 4;
            String prompt = String.format("Enter an integer with less than %d digits: ", maxLength);
            int num = getIntInputBelowCertainLength(prompt, scanner, maxLength);
            System.out.printf("Valid input! You entered: %d, an integer less than or equal to %s characters long%n",
                    num, maxLength);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter an integer with less than 4 digits: a
Error: Invalid input, must be an integer, try again...
Enter an integer with less than 4 digits: 
Error: Invalid input, must be an integer, try again...
Enter an integer with less than 4 digits: 1.0
Error: Invalid input, must be an integer, try again...
Enter an integer with less than 4 digits: 62345
ERROR: Input integer was too long, try again...
Enter an integer with less than 4 digits: 234
Valid input! You entered: 234, an integer less than or equal to 4 characters long
```